# Highcharts, tooltip on hover listing datapoints that do not exist, is it an approximation?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

When I create a stockchart, I noticed by accident that highcharts seems to show or create points that do not actually exist in the data set.

Here is an jsfiddle that illustrates this:

```
( See added comment for the link, unable to just paste it because of idiotic rules on stackoverflow )
```

As you can see **by hovering over** the chart to show the tooltip, some of the data will show as having more than 2 decimals. In the data set there are no such data. All data has a maximum of 2 decimals.

Of course I can do **Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2)** but to me this highlights a bigger problem since I am interested in the actual reported datapoint, and not approximations.

Is there a way to tell highcharts not to do this?

I've tried to use type:'spline' to show data points as illustrated here:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

But couldn't get spline and stockchart to coexist. I would like a stockchart but with **actual** points **dotted** or similar.

Comment: Link to js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is grouped. You can disable data grouping by setting:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/17/

Markers can be enabled using:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/18/